# What are the rules when differentiation functions like this?

Tags: derivatives

So I've had a few questions where I'm given some information like this.

f(2) = 2.             f'(2) = 3

g(2) = 5.             g'(2) = 4

(g/(2f+g))'(2) = ?

So I've tried using the quotient rule for this and got the answer 14/81. However, it wasn't included in the multiple choice options.

The options were:

a) 1

b) 86/81

c) -2/9

d) -1

e) -14/81

I'm really confused as to how the rules of this work and I couldn't find it on the internet since I don't know what these functions are called exactly. Any help and suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hint: take the derivative of the expression $\frac{g(x)}{2f(x)+g(x)}$. (If you did this already, edit your original post to show this attempt.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let

$$
h = \dfrac{g}{2f+g}
$$

Then

$$
h' = \dfrac{g' \cdot (2f+g)- g \cdot (2f+g)'}{(2f+g)^2} = \dfrac{2fg' + gg'  - 2g f' - gg'}{(2f+g)^2}  = 2 \cdot \dfrac{fg' - gf'}{(2f+g)^2}
$$

That means

\begin{align*}
h'(2) & = 2\cdot \dfrac{f(2) \cdot g'(2) - g(2) \cdot f'(2)}{[2f(2)+g(2)]^2} \\
& = 2 \cdot \dfrac{2 \cdot 4 - 5 \cdot 3}{[2 \cdot 2 + 5]^2} = \dfrac{-14}{81}
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you so much! I must've done my calculations wrong.